# React Native: How to fix TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TrackPlayer.STATE_NONE')?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, typeerror, react-native-linking

I entered the following commands in the powershell in the folder containing my alarm app:

```
npm install react-native-track-player
```

```
react-native link react-native-track-player
```

react-native link seemed to have done nothing, so I manually linked the module following the steps given from the [module info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player).

However, when I include the following line in one of my .js components:

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player'
```

I get the following error on my Android device:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TrackPlayer.STATE_NONE')

How can I fix this?

Versions:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.61.5

Here are some screenshots of the stack trace:

1. [Pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FufTK.jpg)
2. [Pt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tlim.jpg)
3. [Pt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCZft.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more information about `react-native` version. Which env you got problem (ios or android).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the suggested info.

Comment: can you edit problem with extra information (code) related to TrackPlayer.STATE_NONE?

Comment: Not sure what code I can include that'll give more information (since simply importing the module caused the error), but I've went ahead and added screenshots of the entire error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

RN `0.61.5` has autolinking so you don't need to link it manually.

First, try to unlink

```
react-native unlink react-native-track-player
```

If you are developing for ios

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Then try to run your project again